# Trying to write 16-bit PNG

Tags: png, tiff, libpng

I'm capturing images from camera, and I have two function for saving 16-bit(!) image one in PNG and one in TIFF formats.
Could you please explain why the PNG is a very noisy image? like this:

PNG function:

```
 bool save_image_png(const char *file_name,const mono16bit& img)
{
    [...]
        /* write header */
        if (setjmp(png_jmpbuf(png_ptr)))
                abort_("[write_png_file] Error during writing header");

        png_set_IHDR(png_ptr, info_ptr, width, height,
                     bit_depth,PNG_COLOR_TYPE_GRAY , PNG_INTERLACE_NONE,
                     PNG_COMPRESSION_TYPE_BASE, PNG_FILTER_TYPE_BASE);

        png_write_info(png_ptr, info_ptr);



        /* write bytes */
        if (setjmp(png_jmpbuf(png_ptr)))
                abort_("[write_png_file] Error during writing bytes");

    row_pointers = (png_bytep*) malloc(sizeof(png_bytep) * height);

        for (y=0; y<height; y++)
            row_pointers[y] = (png_byte*) malloc(png_get_rowbytes(png_ptr,info_ptr));
     for (y = 0; y < height; y++)
     {
             row_pointers[y] = (png_bytep)img.getBuffer() + y * width*2;
     }



        png_write_image(png_ptr, row_pointers);


        /* end write */

  [...]           

}
```

and TIFF function:

```
 bool save_image(const char *fname,const mono16bit& img)
{
  [...]

  for(y=0; y<height; y++) {
    if((err=TIFFWriteScanline(tif,(tdata_t)(img.getBuffer()+width*y),y,0))==-1)
      break;
  }

  TIFFClose(tif);

  if(err==-1) {
    fprintf(stderr,"Error writing to %s file\n",fname);
    return false;
  }
  return true;

//#endif //USE_LIBTIFF
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: I take it this is C? tiff can be written out as raw bytes if need be, but png is a compressed format and can't have raw camera output dumped to it.

Answer (score 1):

`png_set_swap` does nothing. You have to actually flip bytes in each pixel of the image.

If you’re on a PC and have SSSE3 or newer, a good way is `_mm_shuffle_epi8` instruction, make a permute vector with `_mm_setr_epi8`.

If you’re on ARM and have NEON, use `vrev16q_u8` instruction instead.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have a byte-order problem.
Try adding:

```
png_set_swap(png_ptr);
```

before saving the image

Comment: I have placed it before  png_set_IHDR, but got the same result.. (

Comment: if I place it after png_write_info i have got black image

Comment: What about adding png_write_end(png_ptr, NULL); ?

Comment: I have it: `png_write_image(png_ptr, row_pointers);

        /* end write */
        if (setjmp(png_jmpbuf(png_ptr)))
                abort_("[write_png_file] Error during end of write");
        
        png_write_end(png_ptr, NULL);

        /* cleanup heap allocation */
//        for (y=0; y<height; y++)
//                free(row_pointers[y]);
//        free(row_pointers);

        fclose(fp);
       `

Comment: and if I placed it after png_write_info I got not black image (tahnk ImageJ) but too dark for 16-bit image. The maximum intensity was 959 (in ImageJ). But why it 16-bit TIFF the same data look different..?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't think I can help you.

Comment: @Nikolay the TIFF is probably really 12-bit. You can make it use the full 16-bit range by shifting all of the values left by 4 bits.